# How to get foreach loop with item array into a input form

Tags: php

I have to following foreach loop

```
$data = array(
  "success" => false,
  "results" => array()
);

 

      foreach ($cart->get_contents() as $item) {  
      $data['items'][] = array(
        'description' => urlencode($item['name']),
        'amount' => urlencode($item['price']),
        'quantity' => urlencode($item['qty'])
      );
    }         
     
    $data['success'] = true;
```

Now I would like to for the following for each item

```
<input type="hidden" name="' . $field . '" value="' . htmlentities($value) . '">
```

where the `$field` would be the item description, and the `htmlentities($value)` would be the corresponding value from the loop.

Any help welcome as I am not sure where to start, sorry if this is very obvios

Answer (score 0):

I think (if I understand you) that you can achieve this like:

```
$data = [
    'success' => false,
    'items' => [] // Probably itemsm not results??
];

foreach ($cart->get_contents() as $item) {
    $data['items'][] = array(
        'description' => urlencode($item['name']),
        'amount' => urlencode($item['price']),
        'quantity' => urlencode($item['qty'])
    );
}
$data['success'] = true;

foreach ($data['items'] as $item) {
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='" . $item['description'] . "'' value='" . htmlentities($item['amount']) . "'>";
}
```

I also updated the code a little.

Comment: Hi tank you for your reply, how ever what I would like in the input data is <input type='hidden' name='" . $item['description'] . "'' value='" . urlencode($item['name']) . "'> and then loop for each item with the 3 different names, description, amount and quantity witht eh corresponding values. Any idea?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more, three different names? Please provide an exact database output, so we can see what you have

Comment: Sorry, I need to send the description for example where the value is  urlencode($item['name']) so the input would be: <input type='hidden' name='" . $item['description'] . "'' value='" . urlencode($item['name']) . "'> how ever I could have 5 different items  so there could be 5 different descriptions